# Install program on custom build agent azure devops

Tags: windows, sed, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I have downloaded a custom build agent for an Azure Devops release pipeline. I am trying to execute a `sed` statement within the release pipeline, but I am getting an error that the term `sed` is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Any advice on how I can get `sed` installed in a custom build agent would be appreciated.

Comment: Please have a look at the bash task: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/bash?view=azure-devops

Comment: This is a powershell error message. `sed` is a Unix command. You need to specify to run `sed` with bash/Unix.

Answer (score 1):

As per the error message, you are running `sed` in powershell task.

1. Please change to use [Bash](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/bash?view=azure-devops) task as it's a unix based command.
2. Since you're using self-hosted agent, please make sure you have installed `mingw`(you can install [git for windows](https://gitforwindows.org/)(git bash) which include mingw) on windows machine, run `sed --version` locally, make sure it can run successfully. Follow [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67088075/14996050) to add "C:\Program Files\Git\bin" to the Path of Environment Variables, then restart the agent service. You can invoke bash in pipeline now.

My local command:
[image]

My pipeline with bash task:
[image]

Comment: Hi Dave, is there's any update? Let me know if you have any queries.